# 12.04 LTS upgrade error on libuuid1

Tags: 12.04, package-management

In the process of trying to fix a problem with skype on my Ubuntu 12.04 LTS host, I managed to break `libuuid1`, and I have tried everything I could think of:

```
sudo apt-get dist-upgrade
sudo apt-get install libuuid1
sudo apt-get upgrade -f
sudo apt-get -o APT::Immediate-Configure=no upgrade
sudo apt-get autoremove
```

but keep getting the same error which looks like a vicious circle:

```
The following packages have unmet dependencies:
 libuuid1 : Breaks: libuuid1:i386 (!= 2.20.1-1ubuntu3) but 2.20.1-5.3 is installed
 libuuid1:i386 : Breaks: libuuid1 (!= 2.20.1-5.3) but 2.20.1-1ubuntu3 is installed
```

Does anyone have any suggestion on how to fix this, short of reinstalling Ubuntu?

Comment: I resolved my problem by downloading the packages from [pkgs.org](http://pkgs.org/ubuntu-12.04/)  and installing them in this order:  
-`sudo dpkg -i libuuid1_2.20.1-1ubuntu3_i386.deb`  
-`sudo dpkg -i libuuid1_2.20.1-1ubuntu3_amd64.deb`

Comment: You should post that as an answer.

Answer (score 1):

I found this [Ubuntu Forum thread](http://ubuntuforums.org/showthread.php?t=2000234) helpful. Following the instruction from post #4 (The author of which shares source as Steps 1-4 from [Ubuntu documentation](https://help.ubuntu.com/community/Grub2/Installing)
) there once booted to live cd and then chrooted 
Finally I did

```
dpkg --configure -a
apt-get download libuuid1
gdebi ./libuuid1*
```

which was from a cd live session.

On rebooting there are several startup errors that one might encounter what caused the packages post-installation script (postinstall.sh) to fail. These service startup errors will be due to the face that hose services cannot be started while running from the live CD. At this point you should be able to restart and boot to the 12.04 installation then re-run

```
sudo dpkg --configure -a 
sudo apt-get upgrade
```

and . After a rebooting into your shiny new 12.04, those errors will go away!.

Comment: I should mention that after `dpkg --configure -a` I also had to `apt-get download libuuid1` and `gdebi ./libuuid1*`.

Comment: Also, there are several startup errors that one might encounter what caused the packages post-installation script (postinstall.sh) to fail. These service startup errors will be due to the face that hose services cannot be started while running from the live CD. At this point you should be able to restart and boot to the 12.04 installation then re-run `sudo dpkg --configure -a` and `sudo apt-get upgrade`. After a rebooting into your shiny new 12.04, those errors will go away.